# Hiding and displaying all divs on keyboard press

Tags: jquery, html

I am not the most experienced with jquery so I came here hoping to get an answer. The problem I am having is how to hide all of the divs on a webpage, when clicking a keyboard button.

I know the basic code for hiding and showing a div would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hide();  
    $("div").show();
});
```

What I don't know is if there is a easier way to hide every div on the webpage rather than just having a hundred  `$("div").hide();` statements. I also am not sure how to monitor for a click on the keyboard and then hide and show various divs.

Thanks!

Comment: your example would hide all divs. no need for hundreds since the generic selector $("div") would catch all anyhow

Comment: Ah, thank you that's what I was wondering.

Comment: A simple `$("div").hide();` will hide every div on the page. About the keypress, please read the documentation or complete some basic tutorials on event handling with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At its simplest, you'll need to listen to the `keypress` event (or `keyup` or `keydown` events) and, if a particular key is used respond to that event:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't' (for 'toggle'):
        $('div').toggle();
    }
});
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jnpp9/).

References:

- [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    $("div").hide();  
    $("div").show();
});
```

**Taking @nomad's comment into consideration:**

If you want to trigger something on a particular key, you can use [Javascript Key Codes](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)

eg.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 26) {
        alert('You pressed shift key');           
    }        
});
```

Comment: just to expand a tiny bit on what @wirteToBhuwan said you can use `e.Which` or `e.KeyCode` to get which key is being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to identify which letter is pressed

```
$(document).keypress( function( e ) {
   var key = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
   switch( key ) {
      case 'A':
          $('div').hide();
      break;

      case 'S':
          $('div').show();
      break;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
$("div").hide();
```

you are hiding all divs on the page. The selector you're using is the div tag, so all elements with tag "div" will be selected and hide() will be applied to them. So you are already hiding and showing all divs on the page.

To show them when a specific key is pressed, and hide them when another key is pressed, you could do something like the following. This will show the divs when a or A is pressed, hide them when b or B is pressed.

```
$(document).onkeypress(function(e)){
   if (e.which == 97 || e.which == 65){
       $("div").show();
   }else if (e.which == 98 || e.which == 66){
       $("div").hide();
   }
 });
```